# Identity of sum $\sum_{a}^{b}x=-\sum_{b}^{a}x$

Tags: summation

Does $\sum_{a}^{b}x=-\sum_{b}^{a}x $ is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, reversed indexes are interpreted as either

- no term in the sum (i.e. $0$) or
- same as in the normal order.

But never opposite of the sum.

Comment: So I can say that $\sum_{a}^{b}x=\sum_{b}^{a}x $

Comment: @violettagold: as written, but that depends on the exact convention.

Comment: Can you please explain me what is exact convention?

Comment: @violettagold: no, it is up to you.

Comment: For integrals over real intervals we do have the **convention** that $\int_b^a f(x)dx=-\int_a^b f(x)dx$ when $a < b$, so we could extend this to sums, which are a type of integral after all.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma:  for integrals, this is a quite natural convention by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (definite integral as the delta of the antiderivative). For sums, this is less intuitive as they are rarely obtained as "anti-differences).

Comment: True enough, but it probably is the reason for asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: For integrals, it's natural to change the sign, since “$dx$ is negative when you go backwards”. But for sums, there is no $dx$, so $a+b+c$ is the same as $c+b+a$ in the opposite order, not $-(c+b+a)$.